# How to align this table header with its columns in both case scrollbar on overflow & normal

Tags: html, css

If you see the table, you will notice that due to scroll bar on overflow alignment of table header & table rows mismatch.

How to maintain correct alignment among them in both cases: normal or overflow.

Here is the source code below.

```css
table {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 
}
html {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

tbody {
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
 display:table;
 width:100%;
 table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
 width: calc(100%);
}

th{
 background-color: #2c3539; 
 color:white; 
 border: 1px solid black;  
 text-align: left; 
 padding: 8px;
}

td{            
 border: 1px solid black;  
 text-align: left; 
 padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="table" id="dash-board" style="width: 50%;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Total Task</th>
         <th>Done</th>
         <th>Not Done</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>      
      <tr>
         <td>Office-1</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-2</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-3</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-3</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>1</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: What's the point in changing the body to `display:block;`?

Answer (score 1):

just remove

```
overflow:auto
```

from you css file...

here fiddle example
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q420fbm9/)

Comment: thanks @Tommy, However will it work in both cases: during overflow & at normal

Answer (score 1):

For overflowing-y issue you can try width calc on thead you already set that but that calc not woring. Check the css below I just separet the thead and tbody tr class for calc the width. Check scroll-y is working.

```css
.table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
border-collapse: collapse;

}


tbody {
display:block;
height:100px;
overflow:auto;
}
 tbody tr {
display:table;
width: calc(100% - 1px); /*this 1px is the border which cause the overflow-x*/
table-layout:fixed;


}
thead {
  display:table;
width: calc(100% - 17.5px);/*thead Width - (Scrollbar width + border Width) */
   table-layout:fixed;
}

th{
background-color: #2c3539; 
color:white; 
border: 1px solid black;  
text-align: left; 
padding: 8px;
}

td{            
border: 1px solid black;  
text-align: left; 
padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="table" id="dash-board" style="width: 50%;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Total Task</th>
         <th>Done</th>
         <th>Not Done</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>      
      <tr>
         <td>Office-1</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-2</td>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-3</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Office-3</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>1</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```